# Angular 6 - Jquery don't see item with *ngIf directive

Tags: jquery, angular, html

I'm creating app with Angular 6, now I want to add class with jquery hover() method. I have 5 links, everything looks same but 2 of them have added *ngIf directive. It looks like:

```
<li class="nav-item" *ngIf="router.url !== '/video' && router.url !== '/galeria'">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#o-nas">
         O Nas
      </a>
 </li>
```

When I have in route activated link 'video' those 2 li's are removed dynamically.

I want to add class on hover e.g. to change font-size to 50px and all links works but only this 2 of them with `*ngIf` are not.

```
$(".nav-item").hover(
      function() {
        $(this).addClass("link-active");
        console.log("check");
      },
      function() {
        $(this).removeClass("link-active");
      }
    );
```

What's wrong? I have no ideas to fix this

Comment: Can you not just add a css style with the `:hover` selector on it?

Comment: Works same as before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events. then use add class dynamically like `[class.link-active]`

```
<li class="nav-item" [class.link-active]="hover" *ngIf="router.url !== '/video' && router.url !== '/galeria'"
  (mouseenter) ="hover=true "  (mouseleave) ="hover=false">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#o-nas">
         O Nas
      </a>
 </li>
```

Comment: Yup it works perfect, but I must add this to every element right? There's now way to improve this to less code ? I'm only asking :)

Answer (score 1):

**Please, don't use JQuery in your Angular application.**

You have a lot of event to do that.

**onMouseOver**

```
<li on-mouseover='active()' [class.link-active]="active" class="nav-item" *ngIf="router.url !== '/video' && router.url !== '/galeria'">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#o-nas">
         O Nas
      </a>
 </li>
```

**Alternative of mouseOver**

*template*

```
<li (mouseover)='active()' [class.link-active]="hover" class="nav-item" *ngIf="router.url !== '/video' && router.url !== '/galeria'">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#o-nas">
         O Nas
      </a>
 </li>
```

*TS*

```
public hover:boolean = false;
public active(){
   this.hover = !this.hover;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't sure that i can use jquery in angular apps, but thank you for pointing me! It works perfect too

Comment: It's more accurately, by the way

Comment: Hmm a problem with your implementation is that once works, once not, first mouseenter works, mouseleave too, but second not, third mouseenter works, and mouseleave too

Answer (score 0):

Jquery don't see item with *ngIf directive because elements inside a ngIf doesn't exist until the value of ngIf is true. if you have a case like this you should use [hidden] which is basically display none or block but it's not a good idea to use jquery for doing this kind of things inside angular the better approach will be something like @sachila have described above